# MongoDB select distinct and sort

Tags: mongodb

Consider i have data like this:

```
| id   | property | score | remark        |
-------------------------------------------
| aaaa | alpha    | 1     | alpha lowest  |
| bbbb | beta     | 2     | beta highest  |
| cccc | alpha    | 2     | alpha highest |
```

Given data above, i want to select distinct by field `property` and sort it by `score` highest value, so the expected results will be

```
| id   | property | score | remark        |
-------------------------------------------
| bbbb | beta     | 2     | beta highest  |
| cccc | alpha    | 2     | alpha highest |
```

How to do this with mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this by running the following aggregation pipeline operation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "score": -1 } },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$property", 
            "id": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "score": { "$first": "$score" },
            "remark": { "$first": "$remark" }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "_id": 0,
            "property": "$_id",
            "score": 1,
            "remark": 1, 
            "id": 1
        } 
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{ "id" : "bbbb", "score" : 2, "remark" : "beta highest ", "property" : "beta" }
{ "id" : "cccc", "score" : 2, "remark" : "alpha highest ", "property" : "alpha" }
```

Comment: is it possible i can also get object id?

Comment: Do you mean the mongo `_id` or your own custom `id`, as depicted in the question?

Comment: i mean the mongo `_id`, how to do that?

Comment: You can do that within the `$group` pipeline as `"id": { "$first": "$_id" },`, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB has a distinct operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). However, it only returns one "column". You'd need to do multiple queries.
The best option is to use [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/aggregation-introduction/). It works using a [pipeline of operations](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).
I don't know the data, but it could be someting like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { '$group' : { _id : '$property' , score: { '$max': '$score' } } }
])
```

You can use [Robomongo client](https://robomongo.org/) to experiment with this method.